# Sum of increasing power

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What are the results of this:
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a^{i^{2}}$$
and this:
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a^{i^{3}}$$
expressed in terms of $n$, with $a$ being a predefined constant?
Is there any general rule to calculating the sums of series like these for an arbitrary power of $i$?

Comment: No, there is no formula for these sums appreciably simpler than just writing them as sums.

Answer (score 1):

For the first infinite series, what you want to learn about is [Jacobi Theta Functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html).

See, for example, the result in [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20i%20=%201%20to%20infinity%20of%20a%5E%28i%5E2%29).

I don't know of anything corresponding to the second series.